# Unity custom font shader

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using a custom font for Text Mesh.

Everything is fine except when my Text Mesh is near the bottom of the screen. When the Text Mesh is near the bottom is near the bottom, it just disappears in the game window, but it is showed very well in the scene window.

When the Text Mesh's y position -4.99, it works very well. But when I change the y to 5, it disappears, and in the scene window, it is contained by the camera's bounds.

I had tried all the build-in `shaders`, but all of them do not work.

And when the Text Mesh is near other bounds besides bottom(The last picture), it works fine. So how to make it work for the bottom bound?

[image: picture 1][image: picture 2][image: picture 3][image: picture 4]